# How to get memory util of LPARs from HMC?

Tags: virtualization, unix, memory-usage, aix

I know I can get CPU utilizations with `lslparutil` from the HMC.  But is there a way to get memory utilization stats of LPARs from the HMC?  The metrics I found seems to be all configuration-related and not actual memory usage.  Any ideas?

**Edit**:
Specifically, getting the computation/inuse memory? Similar to `svmon -G`?

Answer (score 0):

In my knowledge the HMC does not gather/keep OS memory utilization data, only the memory settings of the "current configuration" and for every profile of the lpar (which you can find in the HMC gui).
These memory settings can be gotten per lpar with a command like the following :
*lshwres -r mem -m $mgsys --level lpar* on the hmc prompt.